# Perfoming a MITM to intercept SSL/TLS with valid certificate

Tags: tls, certificate-authority, hsts

Supposing an attacker is able to perform a Man In The Middle attack and intercept requests from a client that wants to connect to an HTTPS server (let's say www.google.com).

The attacker has a valid certificate (domain : www.randomname.com) signed by Verizon.

He will then redirect the client to his fake server.

Normally, there will be no warning as the certificate is signed by a trusted CA.

Is this a way to bypass HTST protection?

Comment: it's HSTS - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Normally, there will be no warning as the certificate is signed by a trusted CA.

Wrong. Since the subject of the certificate ( www.randomname.com) does not match the URL (www.google.com) the validation will fail and the browser complain. It does not matter if this is "only" a redirect, i.e. even for the domain you redirect from you need a proper certificate.

Comment: The domain name check mecanism is provided by HSTS right?

Comment: @DukeNukem: No, the check of the subject against the name in the URL is part of the normal certificate validation and is done even without HSTS or similar. Without this check  man in the middle attacks would be trivial.